# Dynamically loading aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I found two methods for loading page html dynamically for aspx but only issue is that my txt file is on another server and required to method ask for virutalpath or physical path on webserver.

Is there any way so I can load from azure from url not from filepath or if i can pass only string to PageParser or BuildManager.

Error:

```
The relative virtual path 'http:/tplexcontent.blob.core.windows.net/commonresources/test123.txt' is not allowed here.
```

---

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Method 1
        var pageView = PageParser.GetCompiledPageInstance("/Page2.aspx", "http://tplexcontent.blob.core.windows.net/commonresources/test123.txt", HttpContext.Current);
        (pageView).ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);

        //Method 2
        LoadPage("http://tplexcontent.blob.core.windows.net/commonresources/test123.txt");
    }


    public static void LoadPage(string pagePath)
    {
        // get the compiled type of referenced path
        Type type = BuildManager.GetCompiledType(pagePath);

        // if type is null, could not determine page type
        if (type == null)
            throw new ApplicationException("Page " + pagePath + " not found");

        // cast page object (could also cast an interface instance as well)
        // in this example, ASP220Page is a custom base page
        _Default pageView = (_Default)Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        // call page title
        pageView.Title = "Dynamically loaded page...";
        // process the request with updated object
        ((IHttpHandler)pageView).ProcessRequest(HttpContext.Current);
    }
```